# Lambda expression doesn't working in seemingly identical kotlin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

When trying to create a simple database helper, I have a `RowMapper<T>` from Spring that I want to fill in, but Kotlin insists on using `KFunction2`, even though the interface of `RowMapper` matches. This works on the raw interface from the Spring Java code.

To me it looks like the methods have identical at the important parts. However, Kotlin does not agree with me.

My interface (kotlin) looks as follows:

```
interface MyJdbcOperations : NamedParameterJdbcOperations {
    fun <T> querySingle(
        sql: String,
        parameters: MapSqlParameterSource,
        rowMapper: RowMapper<T>): Optional<T>
}
```

The interface of query inside `NamedParameterJdbcOperations` looks as follows (Java):

```java
public interface NamedParameterJdbcOperations {
    // ... rest of interface omitted for readability

    <T> List<T> query(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)
            throws DataAccessException;
}
```

But when I use my implementation of `MyJdbcOperations` as follows:

```
template.query<Foo>(sql, parameters, this::mapToFoo)
template.querySingle<Foo>(sql, parameters, this::mapToFoo)
```

The first version works, no problem, and I can also remove `<Foo>` and let type inference do its job.

The second version however gives me errors like:

```
Error:(25, 54) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction2<@ParameterName ResultSet, @ParameterName Int, Foo> but RowMapper<Foo> was expected
```

However I actually expected this to just work, if the `KFunction2` signature can satisfy `RowMapper<Foo>` in the Java interface, then I most certainly would expect it to be able to in Kotlin too. This is obviously not the case.

So what am I doing wrong, and what is the best way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found at least one workaround, but I am still puzzled by why this happens and why it doesn't work as expected. The following will solve the immediate problem:

```
    template.querySingle<Foo>(sql, parameters, RowMapper { rs, rowNum -> this.mapToFoo(rs, rowNum) })
```

Thanks to @pietro-martinelli posted an answer that helped me to the right path :)

Answer (score 3):

The key difference I see between the working case and the invocation with compilation error is that the second one refers to a method defined in a Kotlin interface while the first one uses a method defined in a Java interface.

I know that SAM conversion happens from lambas/methods to Java interfaces only, as described here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions .
I can't figure out why this can impact to your scenario, but if you redefine `MyJJdbcOperations` as a Java interface the problem disappears...

This not a real solution but it's a workaround.

It seems that lambdas (I tried with labdas like `{x -> this.mapToFoo(x)}`, too, with the same result you already encountered) and methods passed to Kotlin interface methods are converted to `KFunctionN` and not to the expected interface, also when the expected interface is defined as Java interface...

It's not a complete answer but I hope this can help you to get nearer to the solution.

Comment: Why is this answer not complete? It explains it perfectly. Maybe the correct way would be to not use RowMapper<T> as the argument type, but instead use `rowMapper: (rs: ResultSet, rowNum: int) -> T` in the kotlin interface as the last arguments type? From the same source you linked: "Also note that this feature works only for Java interop; since Kotlin has proper function types, automatic conversion of functions into implementations of Kotlin interfaces is unnecessary and therefore unsupported"

Comment: @sfiss I'm inclined to agree, it's fairly complete indeed :) I think the only part that is missing is actually the addition his answer led me to :)

Using I would argue that using RowMapper is exactly the right thing to do though. First off it communicate the specific intent and the context. What I'm wondering though: is there a way to give a proper function type a name and document them? If not I'm inclined to argue that they might be wrong in claiming that it's "unnecessary"

Comment: Maybe a typealias?  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html Ofc, the RowMapper typealias would be different from spring's RowMapper.

Comment: @sfiss oh, thanks I've been looking for that :) And yeah, definitely better than nothing, but not exactly the same :)